# Inner Interface inside a Class

Tags: java, class, interface

My code is as following, my question is that what is the **meaning of line 1**, if there is not meaning then why does eclipse allows infact gives inner as available option on typing ClassO.

It would have been meaningful if the inner was a static nested class instead of inner interface and **if it meaningful** as it is then **what is the use, what all can i do with it ?**

```
public class InterfaceInsideClass 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ClassO.inner              **// Line 1**
    }

}

class ClassO
{
    interface inner
    {
        void msg();
    }

    class Two implements inner
    {
        public void msg()
        {
            System.out.println("Class Two");
        }
    }

    class Three
    {
        public void msg()
        {
            System.out.println("Class Three not implementing interface but having same method");
        }
    }

    static class Four
    {
        public void msg()
        {
            System.out.println("Class Four");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as any other interface? For example, you can say `ClassO.inner.class.getName()`, or it could contain constants, or static methods..

Comment: Or you could want to create a variable of that type. It's just a type, like any other type.

Comment: Note that Java class and interface names should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: @xs0 - Thanks for the answer, it works fine for static methods but getting error for final variable / constant :-------                                                                              




public class InterfaceInsideClass
       { public static void main(String[] args) 

{ ClassO.inner.i; // Error occurs here } }

 class ClassO 
{ 
interface inner 
{ int i=10; } }

Answer (score 2):

One on the most common use of static nested classes and nested interface is for another layer of packaging.

If the particular interface is only intended to be implemented within a particular class or its subclasses via by its inner or nested classes then it makes sense to include that interface inside those classes.

Good example is: `java.util.Map.Entry`.